# how to open directory and read the files inside that directory using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to unzip the files and counting the matching characters in files , and after that i need to concatenate  the files based on file names. i successfully achieved 1st 2 steps but i am facing the problem to achieve 3rd objective. this is the script i am using.

```
#! use/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print"Enter file name for Unzip\n";
print"File name: ";
chomp(my $Filename=<>); 
system("gunzip -r ./$Filename\*\n");
print"Enter match characters";
chomp(my $match=<>);
system("grep -c '$match' ./$Filename/* > $Filename/output");

open $fh,"/home/final_stage/test_(copy)";
if(my $file="sra_*_*_*_R1")

{
print $file;
}

system("mkdir  $Filename/R1\n");
system("mkdir  $Filename/R2\n");
```

Based on "sra_*_*_*_R1" file name matching i have to concatenate and put the out in R1 folder and "sra_*_*_*_R2" file name R2 folder.
Help me to complete this work, all suggestions are welcome !!!!!

Comment: Use `use warnings` also. `shebang` line is also wrong. Your code have compilation errors.

Comment: after that?? how to print only matching file names?

Comment: After that check you code and correct it.

Comment: First, fix your code, and update your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;
use autodie; # die if problem reading or writing a file
my $dir = dir("/tmp"); # /tmp
my $file = $dir->file("file.txt");# Read in the entire contents of a file
my $content = $file->slurp();# 
openr() returns an IO::File object to read from
my $file_handle = $file->openr(); # Read in line at a timewhile
( my $line = $file_handle->getline() ) 
{        
   print $line;
}
```

Enjoy your day !!!!